# Клонирование элемента в сложной структуре HTML по условию наличия класса

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такая верстка, код всех категория с элемента писать не стал, т.к. у них одинаковая структура.
При нажатии на элемент `.component_option_thumbnail_tap` происходит добавление класса `.selected` к элементу `.component_option_thumbnail` (добавление класса реализовано другим скриптом).

Наша задача - после нажатия на `.component_option_thumbnail_tap` найти `.component_option_thumbnail` и проверить наличие класса `.selected`. Если истина, то клонируем `.thumbnail_price` в `.component_title`. При этом, должна сохранятся "наследуемость" элементов, а так же, если кликать по несколько раз на `.component_option_thumbnail_tap`, клонироваться не должно (т.е. при клике делаем проверку наличия `.thumbnail_price` в `.component_title`) - если есть, то не клонируем, если нет - клонируем.

```html
 <form method="post" class="cart">

     <div class="component">
         <div class="component_title_wrapper">
          <h3 class="component_title product_title">
                 <span class="step_index">1</span>
              <span class="step_title">Категория 1</span>
              <span class="toggle_component_wrapper">
                    <a class="toggle_component" href="#">
                    <span class="toggle_component_text">Toggle</span>
                 </a>
              </span>
              </h3>
           </div>
           <div class="component_inner">
              <div class="block_component"></div>
              <div class="component_description_wrapper"></div>
              <div class="component_selections">
                 <div class="component_selections_inner">
                 <div class="block_component_selections_inner"></div>
                    <div class="component_options" style="">
                        <div class="component_options_inner cp_clearfix">
                            <div class="component_option_thumbnails">
                                <ul class="component_option_thumbnails_container">
                                    <li class="component_option_thumbnail_container first">
                                        <div class="component_option_thumbnail selected">
                                  <a class="component_option_thumbnail_tap" href="#"></a>
                                            <div class="image thumbnail_image">
                                                <img width="300" height="200" src="http://">
                           </div>
             <div class="thumbnail_description">
                                                <h5 class="thumbnail_title title">Элемент</h5>
                                                <span class="thumbnail_price price">
                                                    <span class="amount">700</span>
                                      </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                             </ul>
                                <div class="cp_clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="component_options_select_wrapper">
                                <select class="component_options_select">
                                    <option class="empty" data-title="None" value="">None</option>
                                    <option >Элемент - цена</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cp_clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="component_pagination">
                         <div class="pagination_data"></div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="component_content">
                     <div class="component_summary cp_clearfix">
                         <div class="product content summary_content">
                             <div class="component_data"></div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="component_message bottom">
                     <ul class="msg woocommerce-info"></ul>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="composite_navigation bottom progressive standard">
                 <div class="composite_navigation_inner">
                     <a class="page_button prev invisible" href="#"></a>
                     <a class="page_button next" href="#">Next – Следующая категория</a>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="component">
        <!-- Категория 2 -->
    </div>
    <div class="component">
        <!-- Категория 3 -->
    </div>
    <div class="component">
        <!-- Категория 4 -->
    </div>

</form>
```

Заранее спасибо. Не хватает знаний в *jquery*.

Comment: Подучите js и jquery

Comment: @L.Vadim, сам придумай :D

Comment: Придумал :) ////

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".component_option_thumbnail_tap").one("click",function(){
          if($(".component_option_thumbnail").hasClass("selected"))
          {
           $(".component_title").html($(".thumbnail_price").find(".amount").html()); 
          }
          
        })
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" class="cart">
      <div class="component">
        <div class="component_title_wrapper">
          <h3 class="component_title product_title">
            <span class="step_index">1</span>
            <span class="step_title">Категория 1</span>
            <span class="toggle_component_wrapper">
            <a class="toggle_component" href="#">
              <span class="toggle_component_text">Toggle</span>
            </a>
            </span>
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="component_inner">
          <div class="block_component"></div>
          <div class="component_description_wrapper"></div>
          <div class="component_selections">
            <div class="component_selections_inner">
              <div class="block_component_selections_inner"></div>
              <div class="component_options" style="">
                <div class="component_options_inner cp_clearfix">
                  <div class="component_option_thumbnails">
                    <ul class="component_option_thumbnails_container">
                      <li class="component_option_thumbnail_container first">
                        <div class="component_option_thumbnail selected">
                          <a class="component_option_thumbnail_tap" href="#">asasasas</a>
                          <div class="image thumbnail_image">
                            <img width="300" height="200" src="http://">
                          </div>
                          <div class="thumbnail_description">
                            <h5 class="thumbnail_title title">Элемент</h5>
                            <span class="thumbnail_price price">
                              <span class="amount">700</span>
                            </span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  <div class="cp_clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="component_options_select_wrapper">
                    <select class="component_options_select">
                      <option class="empty" data-title="None" value="">None</option>
                      <option >Элемент - цена</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cp_clearfix"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="component_pagination">
                <div class="pagination_data"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="component_content">
              <div class="component_summary cp_clearfix">
                <div class="product content summary_content">
                  <div class="component_data"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="component_message bottom">
              <ul class="msg woocommerce-info"></ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="composite_navigation bottom progressive standard">
            <div class="composite_navigation_inner">
              <a class="page_button prev invisible" href="#"></a>
              <a class="page_button next" href="#">Next – Следующая категория</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=".component_title"></div>
    
      <div class="component">
        <!-- Категория 2 -->
      </div>
      <div class="component">
        <!-- Категория 3 -->
      </div>
      <div class="component">
        <!-- Категория 4 -->
      </div>
    
    </form>
```

Comment: Почти правильно, я так делал, но как сделать, так, чтобы проход был только по родительскому элементу .component? Ведь их предполагается 6 штук.

Comment: кого  предполагается 6 штук? .component?

Comment: Все верно,  .component будет 6, а может и больше

Comment: это не важно сколько их будет так как он ищет по .component_option_thumbnail .selected, и только тогда выполняет действие. а он один, как я понял

Comment: так помог ответ или нет?